BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 67 on Windows computer
I have installed JDK jdk-23_windows-x64_bin and trying to run Flutter project on Windows computer. Unfortunately, it is giving me this error when I try to build the flutter apk.
Here is the error I am getting:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'K:\Mobile App\ipos\ipos\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\dev.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\ea4ydi90mwjg9g63m7r6nimmx).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 67


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            5.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
I tried JDK version jdk-11.0.24_windows-x64_bin.exe

I updated my answer just now. You can check it out now if your issue persists.

Jdk-23 will not work. Try jdk17 or jdk11 of jetbrains (android studio). (You can use any alternative of these java version)
Further more:
1- Clean flutter and generated build files in your projects android side.
If it does not work then:
1-Update your flutter version, dart version and your .yaml dependencies.
2- Clean flutter and generated build files in your projects android side.
If it does not work and you have not done gradle migration:
1-You should change settings.gradle, build build.gradle and app build.gradle according to documentation. https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
( Alternatively you can update your (1)android studio and (2)flutter plugin of android studio to create a new flutter project. (3)Then compare files that I stated. ( java and kotlin versions stated in documentation))
2- Clean flutter and generated build files in your projects android side.

You encountering the exception,

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit
'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 67

because Java 23 is not compatible with your development setup.
I encountered that exception a few days ago; it works for me by downloading and using Java 17 JDK for Windows from Oracle Java SE 17 Archive Download
After downloading and installing, I updated my PATH and JAVA_HOME, where my newly installed Java 17 is located. It is important to tell your Flutter project to use Java 17 JDK and other Java tools.
Also, I followed Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins configurations.
The most complicated part is that you have to align your project with Gradle Compatibility Matrix, which you need to ensure that you are using a compatible Kotlin version, the Gradle version, which is based on Java 17 that you're using.
Make sure that you're using the latest version of Flutter and considering an updated environment for development (from which I agree with @Bunyamin Basoglu).
After you configure the required setup,
If you find it necessary, perform gradle cache clearing such as (note that you need to cd android to use ./gradlew commands in your terminal)
PS C:\your_project_path\android>./gradlew clean

and/or flutter clean.
Then rebuild your project.
If the issue persists (or there is another exception),
Try these debugging techniques to understand which specific dependencies and packages that introduce the issue:
PS C:\your_project_path\android>./gradlew build --stacktrace --info

To learn more about debugging techniques: read here.
TIPS: Sometimes, Gradle causes the issue, so again, you need to understand the compatibility matrix to ensure that your project development setup is properly configured.
UPDATE:
It's really hard to figure out sometimes, particularly when we encounter that issue occasionally when adding packages, performing an upgrade, etc. The credible reference you can hold usually comes from relevant documentation, relevant forums, and from what your IDE/framework prints out to the logs (i.e., exceptions and warnings). If there's something you're confused about, you have to research the major version, it says.
Here's the relevant reference about the Java major version numbers.
Going back, from this exception:

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit
'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 67

As you can see from the provided link of the Java major version numbers. The major version 67 is equivalent to Java 23 (i.e., incompatible with your current project setup), and we're just recommending Java 17 JDK for Windows from Oracle Java SE 17 Archive Download (without also mentioning that there may be a possible reliable source you can choose from). It is not limited to which, as this is the only way to fix it. This is just because we already encounter issues related to that. But we've decided to use Java 17 (without mentioning we're previously from Java 21). Of course, you can download and try Java 21 and update the necessary PATH, JAVA_HOME, and SDK selection with your IDE. You can verify it by yourself if this is the compatible version you need.
Important notes: Install the compatible JDK version to match your environment and suppress conflict with your installed packages. Try reading this relevant answer that you can use as your guide in testing. The key goal here is to use a compatible Java version that won't conflict with the current development environment and the packages installed.
ADDITIONALS:
Always use a Java long term support (LTS) version.
I hope it helps!

I am running in the exact same problem and am a little confused: Java 23 has been released in september 2024 and the metrics says it supports running gradle 8.10. But when I try to match them, I get similar problems. @Bunyamin Basoglu even refers to try jdk17 or jdk11 which are both way older then Java 23. What am I missing? Where is the problem in matching?

I updated my answer just now. You can check it out now. I hope this makes it more useful now. I agree that it is confusing to understand. But sometimes it is just a bugs, hehehehe, so you have to adjust to suppress those.

@Goku, let me know if you have different findings compared to mine.
